# Post image from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a Base64 encoded image coming in to my application. I want to re-post that image somewhere else, but it's setting the content-type to multipart/form-data at the destination. How do I upload this image?

```
file_name = permitted_params[:file_name]
file_contents = permitted_params[:file_contents]

file = Tempfile.new( file_name )
file.binmode
file.write( Base64.decode64( file_contents ) )
file.rewind()

raw_response = RestClient.put(
    url,
    { 'upload' => file, :content_type => 'image/jpeg' },
    :headers => {:content_type => 'image/jpeg'}
)
```

**UPDATE (SOLVED)**

I needed to use RestClient because I needed to pass it through to another server (hence the 'url' in the PUT).

My problem was in decoding the image I wasn't stripping out the

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,
```

then with this code:

```
raw_response = RestClient.put(url,
                              file_binary,
                              {:content_type => imageContentType})
```

I was able to get it to put the image and set the correct content-type. The answer below did help though, because I tried it to make sure the image was being decoded properly and it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to do. First, you need to decode base64 encoded file. You will get binary file representation. Next use `send_data` from `ActionController` to send binary data. Also I have set a filename so it will be delivered to the user.

```
require 'base64'

class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    file_name            = permitted_params[:file_name]
    file_base64_contents = permitted_params[:file_contents]
    file_binary_contents = Base64.decode64(file_base64_contents)

    # https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data
    send_data file_binary_contents, filename: file_name
  end
end
```

I'll suggest you to update this implementation with error handling to improve security of your app. One more thing, don't use `RestClient`. Why do you need it here? Rails gives you all needed things for HTTP communication from controller.

If you have any questions about this please ask. Good luck.